# Anylogic: Is there a way to delay the output rate of a tank in Anylogic Fluid library?

Tags: anylogic

Using Anylogic Fluid Library, I have a tank that stores liquids, which currently has a variable input rate and a fixed output rate (controlled by a valve). I want it to store the liquid for a period of time before releasing it.

I've tried using the Process Tank, but it doesn't actually process and then release until it's full.

Is that possible to make a tank that can process (need a fix time) and release liquid at the same time?

first tank: stores the liquid needs to be processed

processTank: process and set a time for the process

second tank: for the storage and outflow

[image: 3 tanks design]

Answer (score 0):

Use an Event or DynamicEvent (more flexible) and make it open/close the valve at whatever point you like.

If you want to release it after some time, you can:

1. create a Dynamic Event `My_DE_OpenFlow`
2. in the tank's "on full" code, create in using `create_My_DE_OpenFlow(5, SECOND)` (to wait for 5 sec after being full)
3. in the DE's code, write `myValve.open()` to open the valve in question

Make sure to study and understand Dynamic Events beforehand, though :)

Comment: I tried to solve this problem using 2 tanks and 1 processTank, the first tank to stores the liquid needs to be processed, processTank to process, and the second tank is for the storage. I have posted a picture for this design, but not sure if it is good, maybe you can have a look? I will also try your method to see how it works, thanks a lot.